# How to put user account on hold in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can you teach me how to put a user on hold in my activity in Android? Just like uber Apps. I verify user credential(Background check) before I allow him to have access to the remaining part of the App. I am trying to use Firebase remote configuration, but I do not see how I can put user account on hold with. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

From the Firebase console, you can choose to temporary disable an account and then re-enable it later:

[image: Firebase authentication console]

Comment: Not the right answer. My question is as follow: User A enter its creditential, and press done and my Apps bring him in the homepage and put him on hold until I verify his information (Background check) is correct then , I allow him to have full access for the rest of my Apps (Activities). I do not know if I have to do it from firebase or android studio. I need to set up a process to send me notification when user submit its form and place on hold. Then I verify his account and let him use the apps and start to receive request. Just like uber does. Someone please help.